# Passing a character array to function | Strange error

Tags: c++

Basically I have a buffer in which i am looking for various flags to read certain fields from a binary file format. I have file read into a buffer but as i started to write code to search the buffer for the flags i immediately hit a wall. I am a C++ noob, but here is what i have:

```
void FileReader::parseBuffer(char * buffer, int length)
{
  //start by looking for a vrsn
  //Header seek around for a vrns followed by 32 bit size descriptor
  //read 32 bits at a time
  int cursor = 0;
  char vrsn[4] = {'v','r','s','n'};
  cursor = this->searchForMarker(cursor, length, vrsn, buffer);
}

int FileReader::searchForMarker(int startPos, int eof, char marker[], char * buffer)
{
  int cursor = startPos;
  while(cursor < eof) {
    //read ahead 4 bytes from the cursor into a tmpbuffer
    char tmpbuffer[4] = {buffer[cursor], buffer[cursor+1], buffer[cursor+2], buffer[cursor+3]}; 
    if (strcmp(marker, tmpbuffer)) {
      cout << "Found: " << tmpbuffer;
      return cursor;
    }
    else {
      cout << "Didn't Find Value: " << marker << " != " << tmpbuffer;
    }
    cursor = cursor + 4;
  }
}
```

my header looks like this:

```
#ifndef __FILEREADER_H_INCLUDED__
#define __FILEREADER_H_INCLUDED__

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>



class FileReader {
  public:
    FileReader();
    ~FileReader();
    int open(char *);
    int getcode();
  private:
    void parseBuffer(char *, int);
    int searchForMarker(int, int, char[], char *);
    char *buffer;
};

#endif
```

I would expect to get back a match for vrsn with strcmp but my result looks like this

```
Didn't Find Value: vrsn != vrsn
Found:
```

It looks like it finds it on the second pass after its passed the char array i am looking for.

Relevant hexcode

[image: hex]

Comment: Shouldn't that be something like `int FileReader::searchForMarker(...)` { .... }?

Comment: *Facepalm* yes you are corect i am an idiot

Comment: that fixed it. i was going nuts

Comment: ...Been there...suffered that... :)

Comment: can i ask one more question, and if you want to put as the answer i will accept it. i will update my question too.

Comment: ok, updated. strcmp isnt working right or i dont understand my cursor issue.

Comment: `strcmp` returns 0 if both strings are equal, a negative value if the first is lexicographically smaller, and a positive if it is lexicographically larger. Instead of `if(strcmp(marker, tmpbuffer))`, I am confident, you want `if (strcmp(marker, tmpbuffer) == 0)`.

Comment: thats good to know, thanks Dan!!!

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'm confident he doesn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why? The `if` branch says "Found", the `else` branch says "marker != tmpbuffer". Looks like a classical `if (strcmp(foo, bar) == 0)` to me.

Comment: @DanielFischer: There is nothing "classical" about providing pointers to non-terminated `char` arrays to the `strcmp` function. Well, classical mistake, perhaps. He's using the wrong function altogether.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, overlooked that, thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are right i will look into vector<char> for now im going to temrinate the tmp buffer and compare that to a nulled char array again sorry for all my stupidity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that be something like `int FileReader::searchForMarker(...) { .... }`?

For the second query, I guess the `strcmp` works when it has two null terminated strings as its arguments. For example `str1[]="AAA";` and `str2[]="AAA";` then `strcmp()` would be used as 
 `if(strcmp(str1,str2)==0)` which will return  `0` to indicate that they are equal. In your case, the `tmpbuffer` that you have created is not a null terminated string unless you add `\0` in the end.So you might want to add `\0` in the end of your `tmpbuffer` to create a string of `'v' 'r' 'n' 's'`.

Comment: No, thats not true, the null termination has nothing to do with it. It just compares char arrays. Since my DB format doesn't null terminate, i dont think i should either.

Comment: the issues was just the '==0' rather than expecting a true/false.

Comment: @j_mcnally: Doesn't matter; `strcmp` expects null-terminated strings. Try `strncmp`?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is two-fold:

1. `strcmp` returns "0" on success, not on failure. Read the documentation.
2. `strcmp` expects null-terminated strings. You say that you have chosen non-terminated `char` arrays because that's what your DB library uses. Well, fine. But still, you are violating the requirements of `strcmp`. Use `strncmp` instead (which takes a length argument) or, preferably, *actually write C++* and start using `std::vector<char>` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> char vrsn[4] = {'v','r','s','n'};
> ```

Contains only the 4 characters specified. There is no room for a null character at the end.

> ```
>  char tmpbuffer[4] = {buffer[cursor], buffer[cursor+1], buffer[cursor+2], buffer[cursor+3]};
> ```

Contains only the 4 characters from buffer. There is no room for a null character at the end.

Eventually you call:

> ```
> if (strcmp(marker, tmpbuffer)) {
> ```

The strcmp() function expects each of its parameters to end with a null character ('\0'). It wants to work with strings, which are null terminated.

Since your data is not null terminated, you probably want to use memcmp() instead of strcmp().

Also, strcmp() returns zero when its arguments are equal, so the condition in the if statement is inverted. (Zero is false, everything else is true.) The memcmp() function will also return zero when its arguments are equal.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. `strcmp` expects C-style strings, which are null-terminated. It doesn't care that you have (possibly quite correctly) decided not to use null-terminated strings. So, use something that's not `strcmp`. Why are you using C functions, anyway?

Comment: well it works either way i guess. my marker is 4 chars long, i pass it 4 chars, do a strcmp and it works.

Comment: Paul, i appologize, ive read other places its fine to have char arrays that are not null terminated, if you make an edit, i will un-downvote it

Comment: @j_mcnally: It might magically appear to work for you this time, but maybe next time it won't. Your code can crash, because you are violating the requirements of `strcmp`. Read the documentation. I don't know how you are expecting `strcmp` to be well-defined with just two pointers and no length information!

Comment: No it didn't work. You were lucky. If null characters happen to be laying around in memory after the arrays when strcmp() is called it will appear to work, but some day some time when you least expect it, one or both of the null characters won't happen to be there and the program will mysteriously fail.

Comment: you are all correct, i re-read the docs, and i need null termination. Should i just don't know how that meshes with my format. since my 2nd argument would not be null terminated?

Comment: I am in the wrong here, i am sorry. I am a new to this idk why i wouldnt listen.

Comment: @j_mcnally: I've now suggested two alternatives. Please read what people are telling you.